# Does Canvas object changes between two different runs of onDraw() method?

Tags: java, android, canvas, ondraw

I'm trying to understand if **onDraw** method of the same View/Custom View object runs with exactly the same **Canvas** object?
I tried to examine an implementation when from my code i'm calling **onDraw** method (and without using invalidate method). in the **onDraw** method i'm saving the **Canvas** object that is an input parameter of this method as an object member, and than using this object. I can't understand if it a valid operation, or a **Canvas** object is different between two different runs of **onDraw** method and saving it won't serve  me?

Code (can be an inner Class):

```
private class CustomView extends View
{
   Canvas canvas;
    @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas)
    {
            this.canvas = canvas;
            Path path = new Path();
            if (Utils.isLangRTL()) 
            {
                path.moveTo(lineColor.getWidth(), 0);
                path.lineTo((float) 0.9 * lineColor.getWidth(), lineColor.getHeight());
                path.lineTo(0, lineColor.getHeight());
                path.lineTo((float) 0.1 * lineColor.getWidth(), 0);
                path.lineTo(lineColor.getWidth(), 0);
                canvas.drawPath(path, new paint());
            }
      
    }
```

and than calling the code from somewhere (UI Thread):

```
customView.onDraw(customView.canvas);
```

Comment: you shouldn't be calling onDraw manually.

Comment: @Blackbelt, Thanks for the answer. But as i wrote, i'm looking for an explanation and not for fact that says "don't do"

Comment: The onDraw gets called by android when it is time to draw your view. If you wanna force a draw call the invalidate (). The canvas object is passed down from the parent class

Comment: @Blackbelt, ok. i see, and parent call draw method of "son" class with different canvas between different calls? 
Cause when i tried with i have wrote it work.. But maybe it works cause i have worked on a specific example, and when i will have a big tree hierarchy, it won't work